# While Running PowerMock getting some exception, hence not able to run Test Cases

Tags: powermockito, powermockrunner

java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error: Failed to find the "modifiers" field in method setInternalState.

at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.sedModifiersToField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2348)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.removeFinalModifierIfPresent(WhiteboxImpl.java:2312)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2298)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:304)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:317)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState(Whitebox.java:190)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2412)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.sedModifiersToField(WhiteboxImpl.java:2342)
... 19 more